# How are these statements about CTT reconcilable?

Tags: type-theory

From http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Computational_type_theory#Judgements_and_Propositions:

> The other kind of logical claim made in CTT is the judgment that a belongs to A. This can be reduced to the equality claim by writing a=a in A.

From http://www.nuprl.org/documents/Constable/naive.pdf:

> It does not make sense to regard a in B as a proposition; for instance, it is not clear what the negation of a in B would mean.

and again, from the same paper:

> Also we can define an empty type, void. $$ void= \{ x:A \space |\space x \neq x \space in \space A \} $$

If $a\space in\space B$ can be written $a=a\space in\space B$, then surely the negation of $a\space in\space B$ is $a\neq a\space in\space B$?

Comment: Before answering this, do you understand the difference between a judgment and a proposition in the sense of type theory? That may be the first stumbling block.

Comment: My current understanding is: a proposition is a claim that can turn out to be true or false - it can be considered as a set of proofs, where the set being empty means the proposition is false; a judgment is something that is true because we have decided that it is?

Comment: It is also very important to note that a judgment is "top level", it is a basic building block of the formal system, whereas a proposition is something that lives "inside" type theory. It is an object in the theory.

Comment: Judgments are not about being true or false. They are basic "constructors" from which we build derivations. For instance, you can have a judgment which tells you how to build an ordered pair. What's "true" about that?

Comment: @AndrejBauer thank you, this is making more sense now. So does that mean `a=a in A` is a judgment, too? What is meant by "logical claim"?

Comment: Logical claim is synonymous with Judgment. The issue here, I believe is that $a = a\mbox{ in }A$  is a judgment in the first textbook, but a *proposition* in the second! This means that the texts are in agreement, but they diverge in notation.